# Sails.js, when defining views for rest routes, does data get passed req.locals?

Tags: javascript, rest, routes, sails.js, view

I am new to Sails but had a question regarding using rest routes and views. 
Ive noticed that if you define pages mapping to the default rest route controller actions (findOne,find ect) that Sails will automatically render the correct view.

My question is, when it does this does it return the result of the (findOne/find) to the view it displays and if so how do I access the returned data?

Ive tried accessing req.locals and defining a controller UserController, and a view User/findOne.ejs

however in my view I tried to access the keys in req.locals:

```
<% _.each(req.locals, function (key) { %>
<li><%= key %></li>
<% }) %>
```

No keys were in req.locals.

Also, is using the default rest routes a bad practice (for a production environment)? Assuming correct policies?

When would be an appropriate time to override default rest route actions? Do the default rest routes use req.wantsJSON() to determine if a view should be rendered or JSON returned?

Thanks to anyone who can answer these questions for me, having trouble finding the answers in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, I found the answer.

its located within 'data' inside the view for all default rest routes.